# Ignore certain part of line while matching using regex/grep

Tags: regex, grep, pattern-matching, match

I have plenty of log files that all share the same pattern, DATE TIME USER TEXT, as follows:

```
2015-09-19 21:19:13     Daniel  you should use gpt
```

In the above example, "Daniel" is just a random username, and whatever comes after is text that "Daniel" wrote: "you should use gpt".

What I am after is a way of being able to ignore everything to the left of the username ("Daniel"), **including Daniel**, I will never want to match a username, and then start matching what I need using regex. I only need to match within the actual TEXT the USER wrote.

These log files contains IRC-Chat logs from several different IRC servers / tens if not hundreds of different rooms, that were logged over the years.
All of these log files are under the same folder, without any sub-folders, so applying the grep to * will do.
 I need to be able to grep-match a specific username (every run It will be a different username and I Will edit the grep accordingly of course), where that Username was mentioned (Highlighted) in the chat (Lines), but not when the actual user was the one writing the line, only when mentioned by others.

The following should match because a USER (Jacob) other than Daniel mentioned him (Remember, Jacob here is just a USER):

```
2015-09-19 21:19:13     Jacob  you should read a book Daniel
```

The following should not match because it was USER who mentioned USER:

```
2015-09-19 21:19:13     Daniel  my name is also Daniel
```

The following should not match because relevant USER is not within the TEXT:

```
2015-09-19 21:19:13     Daniel  you should use gpt
```

The pattern remains intact always, only thing that can change is the values of the date & time, length of the USER and obviously the TEXT.

The delimiters are spaces only as in the example, that's an actual copy&paste.

Comment: what is the delimiter between fields? Try to provide a more relevant sample input please. Also, what is the final goal here? What would the final output look like?

Comment: Edited main post to highlight my actual need of using grep in combination with regex while going through these log files I have, It might be simpler than I initially described, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '^([^ \t]+[ \t]+){3}\K.*' file
```

Output:

```
you should use gpt
```